# PyQt: Drag & Drop Pixmap outside the application doesn't work for child widgets

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, widget, pyqt, drag

I want to use an icon to represent my item while drag it outside the application (like the desktop). As long I use a widget on the parent level, it works fine.

Working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setText('%d,%d' % (e.x(), e.y()))

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(self)

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos())

        if drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction) == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction:
            print 'moved'
        else:
            print 'copied'

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        QtGui.QPushButton.mousePressEvent(self, e)
        if e.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print 'press'

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        button = Button('Button', self)
        button.move(100, 65)

        self.buttons = [button]

        self.setWindowTitle('Copy or Move')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 150)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

But when I want to implent this functionality inside my child widgets, it is only working inside the application:

```
class Item(QtGui.QListWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Item, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setText('%d,%d' % (e.x(), e.y()))
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(self)

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos())

        if drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction) == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction:
            print 'moved'
        else:
            print 'copied'

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        QtGui.QListWidget.mousePressEvent(self, e)
        if e.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print 'press'


class ListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setMovement(QtGui.QListView.Static)
        self.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)
        self.setResizeMode(QtGui.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setSpacing(5)

        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        for name in ["Item_01","Item_02", 'Item_03', 'Item_04']:
            item = Item()
            item.setText(name)
            self.addItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app =  QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = ListWidget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How could I bring this to work inside my second example?
It should also work when I implement my custom `ListWidget` inside different other widgets.

Thanks